# How to pause or stop the current playing audio?

Tags: ios, audio, ios7, uibutton

In my application, I have one audio file. I want pause or stop the audio by clicking the button. I have tried  with some code, but it still plays the audio. Please tell how to pause the audio or stop it by clicking the button.

Stop code.

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self.audioPlayer isPlaying];
    [self.audioPlayer stop];
}
```

I have used the above to stop the playing audio but its not working.
where am I doing wrong? How to stop the audio?

Comment: What is `self.audioPlayer`?

Comment: Check for the object of audioPlayer. Are you allocating it number of times or it is the same as you allocated

Comment: Post your audio playing code

Comment: @ Darshan Kunjadiya he did the same thing dude:)

Comment: @user3427551 check your AVAudioPlayerDelegate is delegated or not .

Answer (score 0):

Stopping Audio is easy just you need to take 2 Action Method for 2 separate buttons 1->Play and 2->Stop then code is as fallows

```
-(IBAction)Play:(id)sender
{
[self.audioPlayer play];
}

-(IBAction)Stop:(id)sender
{
[self.audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Another way is to use BOOL and use the 1 Action method to play and stop like this

First declare BOOl object

```
BOOL AudioBool;


-(IBAction)Audio:(id)sender
{
   if(AudioBool == YES)
    {
      [self.audioPlayer play];
       AudioBool = NO;
    }
   else
     {
       [self.audioPlayer stop];
        AudioBool = YES;
     }
}
```